# How to embed an html page with an html page

Tags: html, object, iframe

I have an web site in which i would like to add an HTML page i.e)Google translator

I have included the HTML page using object tag

**My Code**

```
<div align="centre"><object align ="centre" type="text/html" data="a.html" height=1000 width=900> </div>
```

But this some times fails for site like http://stackoverflow.com it opens the HTML of the file in the web page instead of opening it within the website

Then i used Iframe it showed the following error

**My code**

```
<div align="centre"><iframe src="/a.html" height=1000 width=900> </iframe></div>
```

**Error**

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/king/a.html not found

/a.html not found 404 error
```

Here xxx is my IP

**P.S.** I have a HTML file a.html and I want to show it within my website

**Edit** Structure of folder

[image]

--final folder

|

|

|---start.html

|---a.html

|---proy-ui.py

Comment: The 'align' attribute was deprecated years ago and that property value is 'center' not 'centre'. Also, you aren't closing your object element.

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a simpler test case so you can isolate where your real problem lies. Right now the problem could be with your python routing, browser etc etc.

Comment: do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No it doesn't show any error

Comment: Instead of hosting the website if I  open only the start.html I am getting the correct format

Comment: open `a.html` simply in browser and check if a blank page is displayed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76996/discussion-on-question-by-kalaivannan-how-to-embed-an-html-page-with-an-html-pag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling it from the same root directory try removing the forward slash before the file name.  Change your iframe src to the following:

`<iframe src="a.html" height=1000 width=900></iframe>`

**edit:** Upon further investigation, OP was trying to iframe 'https://stackoverflow.com/' which happens to be a site that does not allow itself to be iframed.

Comment: What is in the content of a.html?  If you no longer are getting errors, it is likely that it is working successfully and that your a.html is an empty file.

Comment: To see the iframe working with a live URL try the following with Google as an example:

`<iframe src="http://www.google.com" height=1000 width=900></iframe>`

Comment: Y so if I open the html I get stack overflow page with no css and all

Comment: @kalaivannan - You cannot iframe stackoverflow because they disallow it.  Try `http://www.google.com` instead for a working example.